# PHP Cookie does not work after MySQL result?

Tags: php, setcookie

why i can't set cookie in this code ?
i have no output or anything else befor setcookie, i just want to set user id cookie after found in database, i can see 1 after set my user and password stored in database, but i can't set cookie

```
<?php
include('db_conector.php');
$InternalUser=$_GET['uid'];
$InternalMD5=$_GET['pid'];
$ActiveLink=$_GET['sended'];
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
$InternalUser= mysql_real_escape_string($InternalUser);
$InternalMD5= strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string(($InternalMD5)));
if ($ActiveLink == 'sended'){
    $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM userslist WHERE email = '$InternalUser' AND password = '$InternalMD5'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count > 0){

    setcookie( "userlogin", "anonymous", $expire, "/" ) ;

    echo "<h1 id='CHECK'>1</h1>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<h1 id='CHECK'>0</h1>";
    }
}
mysql_close;
?>
```

also my db connector :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "mydb3", "2525")
or die(mysql_error());   
mysql_select_db("register", $con)
or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `db_conector.php` file is sending out some headers?

Comment: no ,this is my db connector : 
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "mydb3", "2525")
or die(mysql_error());   
mysql_select_db("register", $con)
or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: What does your code do (or print) at the moment?

Comment: i use this code to print 1 for true in HTML header with CHECK ID to readable for xcode with javascript inspect element or print 0 for false.

Comment: I mean when you run it.

Comment: Is `if($count > 0) {` even true? Like the Zend code style guide suggests, you should remove closing PHP tags `?>` at the end of scripts

Comment: `mysql_close` should be `mysql_close()`

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos :  i run this code after generating link with username and md5 password by xcode, then i request link like this : `domain.com/permission.php?uid=demo&pid=md5code&sended=sended`

Comment: @DanFromGermany : no, it's not always true, i checked that, if i use unvalid data, i will get 0

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius : thank you, i fix that, but set cookie still not working

Comment: You have SQL injection in your code and the mysql_ functions are deprecated

Comment: If the file is encoded in UTF-8 with BOM you will have output before even starting the script!

Comment: Wild suggestion: Have you tried to `setcookie` before the rest of the code? I would do that and move it downwards until I find who is guilty.

Comment: @Darhazer : thank you man, i change encode to ANSI and remove blanking space from db connector then my code work perfectly.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos : i did that before ask this question, when i set cookie in top of my code, i could see my cookie, but when i put that back into conditions after mysql result, setcookie did't work

Comment: @Milad Ahmadipour As in Armage's answer then, I would try to avoid using the db_connector.php file, and paste that code into my main php file, to eliminate all possible scenarios. It would be helpful if you explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Darhazer : where is my sql injection ? what is your suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you display the PHP warning ?
You may have a blank character at the end of the included db_connector.php that is sent to the navigator. So the cookie can't be sent (as output is already started with that blank character).
PHP generates a warning in that case.

You also may have problem with cookie depending on your network (like when your web server is behind a proxy). Solution is then in proxy setting, not in PHP code, ask your sysadmin ;).

Comment: thank you, i remove blank space from dbconnector and change my encoding from utf8 to ansi, my code did work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery

```
echo '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
echo '<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/12192541330/jquery-cookie.js"></script>';
echo '<script>$.cookie("__cookie_name__", __value__, {expires: __days__, path: \'/\'});</script>';
```

instead of this

```
setcookie( "userlogin", "anonymous", $expire, "/" ) ;
```

if it doesn't work too then you need to check your (mysql_query & mysql_num_rows) results

```
if(!$query){ echo mysql_error(); }
if(mysql_num_rows($query) <= 0) { echo mysql_error(); }
```

Comment: thank you, i remove blank space from dbconnector and change my encoding from utf8 to ansi, my code did work perfectly